# How should my node/express RESTful API should return database errors to the clients?

Tags: node.js, express

Right now if there is an error, such as duplicate entry, I return it like this `res.status(500).send(err);`

Showing the client this kind of things:

```
{
    "code": "ER_DUP_ENTRY",
    "errno": 1062,
    "sqlMessage": "Duplicate entry 'name@mail.com' for key 'user_table_email_unique'",
    "sqlState": "23000",
    "index": 0,
    "sql": "update `user_table` set `email` = 'name@mail.com' where `id` = 3"
}
```

What is the standard way of doing this? I want the client to know what kind of error is but not, for example,  the name of my tables

Comment: Possibly opinion based?

Comment: It depends, is your client a normal user or a develop. In both cases, you should hide the table and field names and just send a custom error message. You can also just send **http 409** to tell its a duplicate entry.

Answer (score 0):

without seeing your code structure it's difficult to help, but if you have your query in a function that returns to your main script you could catch there, process the error and then throw a succinct and non-data exposing error back to the calling function.

```
// This is pseudocode
const updateEmail = (db, email, id) => db.query('query...')
  .then(data => /* process things */)
  .catch(err => {
    if (err.errno === 1062) {
      throw new Error('Email already exists');
    }
  });
```

I'm not certain that 500 is the correct code to use in this particular case either, as it isn't a server error per se. That would be a preference thing though depending upon how your other requests are structured.